PlayWright error : "Internal error: unable to connect to the test server"
When i install PlayWright i see this error, i've tried installing on a different machine with no problems. But the machine where i need it to work i get that error.
[{
    "resource": "/c:/Code/playwright/playwright.config.ts",
    "owner": "pw.testErrors.diagnostic",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Internal error: unable to connect to the test server",
    "source": "playwright",
    "startLineNumber": 1,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 1,
    "endColumn": 1
}]


Any ideas?
I tried repeated installs, uninstall, reinstall. Nothing seems to change that error

What's your playwright.config.js look like, and are you trying to connect to a test server or not? If you are, then debug why the webServer config isn't set up properly, otherwise remove it entirely.

I recommend to file an issue on GitHub

I did, thank you.

I encounter the same issue when using playwright with ts

This answer does not provide a solution or any useful information to address the issue. Please provide more details or a potential solution to help the user.

If you are using symlinks in any part of the path to your project, that can cause this error to show.  It appears the VSCode extension for playwright does not recognize/follow symlinks, or at least it cannot find the "test server" across them.  I ran into this same issue, but when I opened up the project via the physical path, I did not receive the same error.
https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/33317
